# what happens if I turn off a device before "sync"?

Tags: c, linux, data-synchronization

I have an embedded device (Linux + BusyBox) on which I loaded a file `"my_file.txt"`. I used `cat` to check the contens of the file, and it was satisfactory. Then, I pulled the plug and after reboot, I saw the file was still there, but with 0 bytes size...

Can that be caused by an unsync file-system? This is actually a double-sided question:

1. Is the createion of a file and the copy of its contens happen in different stages? (allowing a phase wehre a file with 0 bytes exists)
2. Is it possible that I "see" the file *[meaning I successfully managed to `cat "my_file.txt"`]*, but what I actually see, is a cached version that will not be there after reboot, unless a `sync` will be called?  <sub>*and by "not be there" I mean the contens, as the file itself remains*</sub>

*BTW, when does Linux flush filesystems? I know that `stdout`, for example, is flushed (by default) when a `"\n"` is introduced [and can be configured somehow, don't remember exactly how]. Is there a rule for filesystems as well?*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it's not programming related and would be better served at unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux

Comment: Why isnt this a programming question? I essentially ask about how exactly the functio `sync` works and what happens in the background

Comment: Because you're asking about the functionality of something someone else wrote; you're not programming, you're consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the createion of a file and the copy of its contens happen in different stages? (allowing a phase where a file with 0 bytes exists)

Yes. The normal operation on files are

1. open/create the file
2. read/write data.
3. close the file.

> Is it possible that I "see" the file [meaning I successfully managed to cat "my_file.txt"], but what I actually see, is a cached version that will not be there after reboot, unless a sync will be called?

Yes. If step 1 above was synced to the hard drive, but step 2 was not, you lose the file content.

> BTW, when does Linux flush filesystems? I know that stdout, for example, is flushed (by default) when a "\n" is introduced [and can be configured somehow, don't remember exactly how]. Is there a rule for filesystems as well?

No, there are no general rules - it's complicated. The OS/Kernel and filesystem caches data in RAM and writes it to disk when its internal algorithms figure out it's a good time to do so.

Note that there are flush/sync'ing on many levels. The flushing you talk about "when a "\n" is introduced", is only a flush from a program down to the operating system. The operating system might then keep the data in RAM only and flush it to a hard drive later.
The hard drive might even cache it in RAM onboard the harddrive and write it to permanent storage later on.

Normally you can run the `sync` command on a command line to ensure all cached data is written from the OS to the hard drive. (Albeit on low-end hard drives with onboard RAM that is not battery backed up, this could still lose data that resides in the ram onboard a harddrive if power is cut).

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning `fsync` and `fdatasync`, which is the programmer's interface for making sure a file's data is actually written out the storage.

Comment: @thatotherguy what about plain `sync` - this is what I tried to use?

Comment: `sync` is a command you can run (or a function a program can call) to sync all files in the entire system to the underlying storage. `fsync/fdatasync` are functions a program can call, e.g. right before closing the file, to ensure data for that single file is synced to the underlying storage. `fsync/fdatasync` operates on a single open file, `sync` operates on all files.

Comment: The rules in Linux and other POSIXy/UNIXy systems aren't very complicated: *"when it sees fit, is forced to, or the filesystem is unmounted"*. The "when it sees fit" *is* complicated, but nobody should rely on that part, ever, anyway. Proper software-based shutdown in Linux does a lot, including telling the hard drive to shut down, to ensure data integrity. Users should use that, rather than find rules-of-thumb on when just pulling the plug should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is the createion of a file and the copy of its contens happen in different stages? (allowing a phase wehre a file with 0 bytes exists)

Yes, copying a file is not an atomic operation as you first call to `open()` and then `write()` after... Opening with `O_CREAT` mode will create an empty file, so yes : first an empty file which is filled after.

> 2. Is it possible that I "see" the file [meaning I successfully managed to cat "my_file.txt"], but what I actually see, is a cached
>      version that will not be there after reboot, unless a sync will be
>      called? and by "not be there" I mean the contens, as the file itself
>      remains

Yes exactly, what you saw is a cached version of the previous operations.

> when does Linux flush filesystems?

The general rule is that the kernel flushes things when it wants. The only thing you can do is to ask for the flushing, but alas even this is just an asking and doesn't means that the flush occurred, it just means that the flush will occur soon. The corresponding command line is `sync`.

> Is there a rule for filesystems as well?

You may mount a filesystem requesting that IOs will be made in direct mode, or you can request for it on a file-by-file basis (see `O_DIRECT` and alikes in `open`). But be aware that direct mode generally drops the performances...

Answer (score -1):

if you turn off the device while you are working with file in your project it can be destroyed your file because for example you want erase your file's document and write again into it.my be you device turn off between these two stage and your file destroy.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the questions.